# Cursor pointing hover animation in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I have SVG as an image file where I want to do this cursor hover effect.
I tried onhoverbutton but that does not work here.
I am using flutter_svg package for showing SVG image

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 400,
            child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/below.svg',
                cacheColorFilter: true,
                color: const Color(0xff2C66B8)),
          )
```

---

This is what I want in my web-app

[image: video gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run below code in dartpad, you will get idea about how hover works in flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MouseRegion with custom cursor',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: MouseRegionWithCustomCursor(
        cursor: const Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Colors.white),
        // here you have to replace this with your svg image
        child: Container(width: 300, height: 200, color: Colors.blueGrey),
      ),
    );
  }
}


// and in this class  you can implement your blue line expansion and compression lines
class MouseRegionWithCustomCursor extends HookWidget {
  final Widget cursor;
  final Widget child;

  const MouseRegionWithCustomCursor({
    Key? key,
    required this.cursor,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cursorPosition = useState<Offset?>(null);
    return MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.none,
      onHover: (event) => cursorPosition.value = event.localPosition,
      onExit: (event) => cursorPosition.value = null,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          child,
          if (cursorPosition.value != null)
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: const Duration(),
              left: cursorPosition.value?.dx,
              top: cursorPosition.value?.dy,
              child: cursor,
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i know this is not best explanation but you can start with this.